# Is the collapsed Cantor set homeomorphic to the interval $[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, cantor-set

If I take the Cantor ternary set constructed on the interval $[0,1]$ and collapse the spaces between the points of the Cantor set, do I obtain an interval again? My intuition tells me that it should be so because the Cantor set is equipotent to the interval $[0,1]$, but I'm not sure how to prove it. Essentially, is the collapsed Cantor set homeomorphic to the interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `collapsing'? I think the process cannot be done in finite steps, so you should give exact way of collapsing.

Comment: By "collapsing" I mean taking all the points in the complement of the Cantor set and identifying them to a single point, while the points that are in the Cantor set are identified with themselves.

Comment: If you take the ternary representation of the Cantor set as those values which are representable using digits $0$ and $2$ but no digit $1$, then you might see "collapsing" as dividing each digit by $2$ (so now with digits $0$ and $1$) and reading the result as a binary number.  You need to decide what to do about numbers like $\frac13=0.0\bar2_3=0.1\bar0_3$ and $\frac23=0.2\bar0_3=0.1\bar2_3$, as they might each become $0.0\bar1_2=0.1\bar0_2=\frac12$.  So this shows the problem: there is nothing between $\frac13$ and $\frac23$ in the Cantor set, and a real interval does not have this property

Comment: If you identify each pair of points in the Cantor set which belong to the same complementary interval, the quotient space is indeed homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. Hint: Use the Cantor function.